# Extract rows using different info in different columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a big data file containing different information. I need to select and copy only some rows of this file in another one.

`my_file.txt` (Column are separated by `"tab"`. I reported only the first column, but after that there is other information)

There are 2543 rows and 22 columns.

```
4gga_A_001_______________   clust_001   APC-coactivator_clust_001   4GGA-A  Q12834  2.04    CDC20   APC-coactivator
4ggc_A_002_______________   clust_001   APC-coactivator_clust_001   4GGC-A  Q12834  1.35    CDC20   APC-coactivator
4ggd_A_002_______________   clust_001   APC-coactivator_clust_001   4GGD-A  Q12834  2.43    CDC20   APC-coactivator
4n14_A_002_______________   clust_001   APC-coactivator_clust_001   4N14-A  Q12834  2.1 CDC20   APC-coactivator
5g04_R_002_______________   clust_001   APC-coactivator_clust_001   5G04-R  Q12834  3.9 CDC20   APC-coactivator
5khu_R_006_______________   clust_001   APC-coactivator_clust_001   5KHU-R  Q12834  4.8 CDC20   APC-coactivator
5lcw_Q_002_______________   clust_001   APC-coactivator_clust_001   5LCW-Q  Q12834  4.2 CDC20   APC-coactivator
6q6g_R_004_______________   clust_001   APC-coactivator_clust_001   6Q6G-R  Q12834  3.2 CDC20   APC-coactivator
6q6h_R_003_______________   clust_001   APC-coactivator_clust_001   6Q6H-R  Q12834  3.2 CDC20   APC-coactivator
6q6g_R_005_______________   clust_016   APC-coactivator_clust_016   6Q6G-R  Q12834  3.2 CDC20   APC-coactivator
6q6h_R_002_______________   clust_017   APC-coactivator_clust_017   6Q6H-R  Q12834  3.2 CDC20   APC-coactivator
1u6d_X_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   1u6d_X  Q14145  1.85    KEAP1   BTB
1zgk_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   1zgk_A  Q14145  1.35    KEAP1   BTB
2vpj_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   2vpj_A  Q53G59  1.85    KLHL12  BTB
2xn4_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   2xn4_A  O95198  1.99    KLHL2   BTB
3vng_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   3vng_A  Q14145  2.1 KEAP1   BTB
3vnh_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   3vnh_A  Q14145  2.1 KEAP1   BTB
3zgc_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   3zgc_A  Q14145  2.2 KEAP1   BTB
3zgd_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   3zgd_A  Q14145  1.98    KEAP1   BTB
4ch9_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   4ch9_A  Q9UH77  1.84    KLHL3   BTB
4chb_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   4chb_A  O95198  1.56    KLHL2   BTB
4ifj_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   4ifj_A  Q14145  1.8 KEAP1   BTB
4ifl_X_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   4ifl_X  Q14145  1.8 KEAP1   BTB
4ifn_X_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   4ifn_X  Q14145  2.4 KEAP1   BTB
4in4_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   4in4_A  Q14145  2.59    KEAP1   BTB
4iqk_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   4iqk_A  Q14145  1.97    KEAP1   BTB
4l7b_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   4l7b_A  Q14145  2.41    KEAP1   BTB
4l7b_B_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   4l7b_B  Q14145  2.41    KEAP1   BTB
4l7c_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   4l7c_A  Q14145  2.4 KEAP1   BTB
4l7d_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   4l7d_A  Q14145  2.25    KEAP1   BTB
4n1b_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   4n1b_A  Q14145  2.55    KEAP1   BTB
4xmb_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   4xmb_A  Q14145  2.43    KEAP1   BTB
5f72_C_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   5f72_C  Q14145  1.85    KEAP1   BTB
5nkp_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   5nkp_A  Q9UH77  2.8 KLHL3   BTB
5wfl_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   5wfl_A  Q14145  1.93    KEAP1   BTB
5wfv_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   5wfv_A  Q14145  1.91    KEAP1   BTB
5wg1_A_002_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   5wg1_A  Q14145  2.02    KEAP1   BTB
5whl_A_002_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   5whl_A  Q14145  2.5 KEAP1   BTB
5whl_B_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   5whl_B  Q14145  2.5 KEAP1   BTB
5who_A_002_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   5who_A  Q14145  2.23    KEAP1   BTB
5who_B_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   5who_B  Q14145  2.23    KEAP1   BTB
5wiy_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   5wiy_A  Q14145  2.23    KEAP1   BTB
5wiy_B_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   5wiy_B  Q14145  2.23    KEAP1   BTB
5x54_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   5x54_A  Q14145  2.3 KEAP1   BTB
5yq4_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   5yq4_A  Q9Y2M5  1.58    KLHL20  BTB
5yy8_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   5yy8_A  Q9Y6Y0  1.98    IVNS1ABP    BTB
6fmp_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   6fmp_A  Q14145  2.92    KEAP1   BTB
6fmq_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   6fmq_A  Q14145  2.1 KEAP1   BTB
6gy5_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   6gy5_A  Q9Y2M5  1.09    KLHL20  BTB
6hws_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   6hws_A  Q14145  1.75    KEAP1   BTB
6n3h_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   6n3h_A  Q9Y6Y0  2.6 IVNS1ABP    BTB
6rog_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   6rog_A  Q14145  2.16    KEAP1   BTB
```

I need to extract rows using the values in 3rd, 5th and 6th column. In details, for equal third column strings (e.g. APC-coactivator_clust_001, or APC-coactivator_clust_016 ...) I must extract the row to which corresponds, for each different fifth column value (e.g. Q12834 ...) the lowest sixth column value.
I don’t know if I was clear enough. Anyway I bring you the output file that I should get.

```
outpout.txt

4ggc_A_002_______________   clust_001   APC-coactivator_clust_001   4GGC-A  Q12834  1.35    CDC20   APC-coactivator
6q6g_R_005_______________   clust_016   APC-coactivator_clust_016   6Q6G-R  Q12834  3.2 CDC20   APC-coactivator
6q6h_R_002_______________   clust_017   APC-coactivator_clust_017   6Q6H-R  Q12834  3.2 CDC20   APC-coactivator
1zgk_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   1zgk_A  Q14145  1.35    KEAP1   BTB
2vpj_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   2vpj_A  Q53G59  1.85    KLHL12  BTB
4chb_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   4chb_A  O95198  1.56    KLHL2   BTB
4ch9_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   4ch9_A  Q9UH77  1.84    KLHL3   BTB
5yy8_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   5yy8_A  Q9Y6Y0  1.98    IVNS1ABP    BTB
6gy5_A_001_______________   clust_001   BTB_clust_001   6gy5_A  Q9Y2M5  1.09    KLHL20  BTB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk` and process input file only once:

```
awk 'min[$3, $5]!=""{ if(min[$3, $5]>$6){ line[$3, $5]=$0; min[$3, $5]=$6}; next }
                    { min[$3, $5]=$6; line[$3, $5]=$0 }
END{ for(x in line) print line[x] }' infile
```

To *"keep lines with equal minimum values"* in 6<sup>th</sup> column:

```
awk 'min[$3, $5]!=""{ if(min[$3, $5] >$6){ line[$3, $5]=$0; min[$3, $5]=$6 };
                      if(min[$3, $5]==$6){ line[$3, $5]=line[$3, $5] ORS $0 }; next
                    }
                    { min[$3, $5]=$6; line[$3, $5]=$0 }
END{ for(x in line) print line[x] }' infile
```

Answer (score 4):

With `awk`

```
FNR==NR && !seen[$3,$5]++ {val[$3,$5]=$6}
FNR==NR && seen[$3,$5] {if ($6<val[$3,$5]) {val[$3,$5]=$6} }
 
NR!=FNR && val[$3,$5]==$6
```

Run with

```
awk -f script.awk input input
```

What does it do?

Create a [pseudo-multidimentional array](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html) using columns 3 and 5 as indices and

1. if there is no such element, get value of column 6
2. if there is such element compare values with column 6 and pick smaller one
3. Then rerun through the file and pick each line where the array indices match columns 3 and 5 and the value of column 6 fits the array element.

Runs twice through the file, but has very low RAM occupation. Sorting is as appears in input file.

Answer (score 2):

```
sort -t$'\t' -k3,3 -k5,5 -k6n,6 file | awk -F\\t '!seen[$3,$5]++'
```

The main thing `sort` is used for is the numeric sorting of field 6 - the following would also work:

```
sort -t$'\t' -k6n,6 file | awk -F\\t '!seen[$3,$5]++'
```

However the output would not be grouped by columns 3 & 5. `awk` is used to print the first line containing a unique column 3/5 pair. `"$(printf '\t')"` may be used in place of `$'\t'` in a shell that doesn't support `$'...'` C strings.

awk processing file twice to keep same order as input & also keep lines with equal minimum values:

```
awk '
FNR==NR {if (min[$3,$5]=="" || $6<min[$3,$5]) min[$3,$5]=$6; next} $6==min[$3,$5]
' file file
```

Answer (score 0):

comes out in a different order than your suggested output, so if the order is not critical, this works:

```
sort -s -k3,3 -k5,5 -k6,6n < in | perl -ane 'print unless $seen{$F[2]}{$F[4]}++' > out
```

If the original order is to be maintained, you can run

```
nl < in | sort -s -k4,4 -k6,6 -k7,7n | perl -ane 'print unless $seen{$F[3]}{$F[5]}++' | sort -k1,1n | cut -f2- > out
```

However, even your sample output is *not* preserving the original order (`grep 4ch[9b]_A_001` in your input and output samples and you will see).